# Texture not displaying SDL2

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a game in C++ with SDL2, and I can't even get a texture displaying. SDL_GetError() returns nothing.
I'm on a windows 10 pro using Visual Studio.
Here are my 3 files:

1. main.cpp

```
#include "Classes.h"

int MouseX = 0;
int MouseY = 0;
int PlayerX = 0;
int PlayerY = 0;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
Tile tile = Tile({10, 10, TileTypes::Tile_Grass}, renderer);

EventReturns HandleEvent(SDL_Event* event) {
    switch (event->type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        return EventReturns::Event_QUIT;
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch (event->key.keysym.sym) {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            return EventReturns::Event_TryQuit;
        default:
            return EventReturns::Event_None;
        }
    default:
        return EventReturns::Event_None;
    }
}

int mainLoop(EventReturns eventReturn) {
    SDL_GetMouseState(&MouseX, &MouseY);
    if (eventReturn == EventReturns::Event_QUIT || eventReturn == EventReturns::Event_TryQuit) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void render() {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 200, 200, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    tile.SetPos(0, 0);
    if (tile.Draw(renderer) != 0) {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "ERROR", "ERROR: Rect in tile has 0x0 size, Please close this with the task manager", NULL);
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 2880, 1600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    bool running = true;
    EventReturns eventReturn = EventReturns::Event_None;
    SDL_Event event;
    int quit = 0;
    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            eventReturn = HandleEvent(&event);
        }
        quit = mainLoop(eventReturn);
        render();
        if (quit == 1) {
            running = false;
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

2. Classes.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#define SpriteSizeMult 1

enum class EventReturns {
    Event_QUIT,
    Event_None,
    Event_TryQuit
};

enum class TileTypes {
    Tile_Grass
};

struct TileStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
    TileTypes type;
};

class Tile {
public:
    Tile(int x, int y, char* TexturePath, SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    Tile(TileStruct structure, SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    Tile();

    int Draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer);

    void SetPos(int x, int y);

private:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int TextureWidth = 0;
    int TextureHeight = 0;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect rect;
};

SDL_Point getsize(SDL_Texture* texture);
```

3. Classes.cpp

```
#include "Classes.h"

SDL_Point getsize(SDL_Texture* texture) {
    SDL_Point size;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &size.x, &size.y);
    return size;
}

Tile::Tile(int x, int y, char* TexturePath, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, IMG_Load(TexturePath));
    if (this->texture == nullptr) {
        this->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, IMG_Load("Assets/MissingTexture.png"));
        std::cout << IMG_GetError();
    }
    SDL_Point point = getsize(this->texture);
    this->TextureHeight = point.y;
    this->TextureWidth = point.x;
    this->rect = {this->x - ((this->TextureWidth * SpriteSizeMult) / 2), this->y - ((this->TextureHeight * SpriteSizeMult) / 2), this->TextureWidth * SpriteSizeMult, this->TextureHeight * SpriteSizeMult};
}

Tile::Tile(TileStruct structure, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    this->x = structure.x;
    this->y = structure.y;
    switch (structure.type) {
    case TileTypes::Tile_Grass:
        this->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, IMG_Load("Assets/Tiles/Grass.png"));
    default:
        this->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, IMG_Load("Assets/MissingTexture.png"));
    }
    if (this->texture == NULL) {
        this->texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, IMG_Load("Assets/MissingTexture.png"));
        if (this->texture == NULL) {
            SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "ERROR", "Failed to load texture", NULL);
            SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "ERROR", IMG_GetError(), NULL);
        }
    }
    SDL_Point point = getsize(this->texture);
    this->TextureHeight = point.y;
    this->TextureWidth = point.x;
    this->rect = { this->x - ((this->TextureWidth * SpriteSizeMult) / 2), this->y - ((this->TextureHeight * SpriteSizeMult) / 2), this->TextureWidth * SpriteSizeMult, this->TextureHeight * SpriteSizeMult };
}

Tile::Tile() 
{
}

int Tile::Draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    if (rect.w == 0 || rect.h == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    this->rect.x = 0;
    this->rect.y = 0;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, this->texture, NULL, &rect);
    return 0;
}

void Tile::SetPos(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

I'm sorry for the sheer amount of code that is, but I'd really appreciate the help. If there's any more info I need to put here, just let me know.

I'm fully aware that I should make a Minimal Reproducible Example, but as far as I'm aware, all the code listed here is necessary.

Finally, in case I've been unclear, when running the code the Missing Texture image that should appear isn't showing up.

Comment: Have you tried to minimize the amount of code? One way to try and debug problems is to back up your project, then delete all the parts tha thave nothing to do with the problem. For example, you can delete the tile types, and say all tiles are grass. Then you can delete the tile class and just render directly in the `render` function, and so on. Either you find the problem when doing this (congrats) or you have a smaller amount of code which you don't need to apologize for.

Comment: Hi @user253751, Thanks for suggesting that. I tried also drawing a png in the render script instead of from the class, and the image displayed... I hope that answers your question

Comment: Okay, now you can work backwards and figure out where it stops working, and you've found out exactly where the problem is! If you find where the problem is, but you still can't understand why it's a problem, you can ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see `SDL_INIT` function in your code.
You should add this in the beginning of your main function.

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    return 1;
```

You are initialising tile before creating a renderer so the constructor is trying to create a texture without a renderer.

```
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
Tile tile = Tile({10, 10, TileTypes::Tile_Grass}, renderer);
```

You should do something like this

```
#include "Classes.h"

int MouseX = 0;
int MouseY = 0;
int PlayerX = 0;
int PlayerY = 0;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;


EventReturns HandleEvent(SDL_Event* event) {
switch (event->type) {
case SDL_QUIT:
    return EventReturns::Event_QUIT;
case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    switch (event->key.keysym.sym) {
    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
        return EventReturns::Event_TryQuit;
    default:
        return EventReturns::Event_None;
    }
default:
    return EventReturns::Event_None;
}
}

int mainLoop(EventReturns eventReturn) {
SDL_GetMouseState(&MouseX, &MouseY);
if (eventReturn == EventReturns::Event_QUIT || eventReturn == EventReturns::Event_TryQuit) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

void render(Tile tile) {
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 200, 200, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
tile.SetPos(0, 0);
if (tile.Draw(renderer) != 0) {
    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "ERROR", "ERROR: Rect in tile has 0x0 size, Please close this with the task manager", NULL);
}

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    return 1;
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 2880, 1600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
Tile tile = Tile({ 10, 10, TileTypes::Tile_Grass }, renderer);
bool running = true;
EventReturns eventReturn = EventReturns::Event_None;
SDL_Event event;
int quit = 0;
while (running) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        eventReturn = HandleEvent(&event);
    }
    quit = mainLoop(eventReturn);
    render(tile);
    if (quit == 1) {
        running = false;
    }
}
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't fix the issue, but thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Anonym0us_C0d3r you are initialising tile before creating a renderer so the constructor is trying to create a texture without a renderer